# Partialy applying multiresolution modifier

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution

I have a very low poly mesh which has a multires modifier on it which has subdivisions set to 7. Is there a way i could apply a few subdivisions to the base mesh, but leave the multires modifier unapplied.This is dificult to explain so i will attempt to use images to help explain.
This is the base mesh:
[image]
This is the high res:
[image]
Now could i partly apply the modifier to the base mesh so it ends up lokking something like this:[image]
But still keep the remaining subdivisions in the modifier so I can later apply them?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as of now (as I understand you're asking about something like *Geometry* > *Delete Lower* in ZBrush). The only thing you could make is to execute *Apply Base* to make actual geometry of the mesh (0 subd's) be in accordance with sculpting (rough one).

Answer (score 3):

Old question but still I know at least a work around for this.

If e.g. you want to get rid of the levels 1 to 3 and keep only 4 to 7 you can do this:

1. Duplicate model
2. Go to level of detail you want as lowest (e.g. 4)
3. Apply Modifier
4. Add new modifier and subdivide till you have the same subdivision as the original one (in this case subdivide 3 times)
5. Add a Shrinkwrap modifier and set both Meshes to the highest level
6. Apply Shrinkwrap modifier

Done.