# Apply individual Multires levels

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, multiresolution

I've created a simple landscape model and used the Multires-Modifier to sculpt it. The modifier is set to 3 subdivision for viewport and has a maximum subdivision count of 6 for sculpting and render.
The problem here is that my materials require vertex paint for their blending, which has an incredible low resolution due to the low-poly base mesh.

The solution would be simple: apply the first three subdivisions which gives more resolution for vertex painting while sill having a 0|3 Multires-modifier to keep the information of the sculpted high-poly.

However, the Modifier **can only be applied as a whole**, so i cant just "take the first three levels and leave the rest in the modifier".

Using the shrinkwrap modifier like suggested in [this question from 4 years ago](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66302/partialy-applying-multiresolution-modifier) will lead to a loss of detail and distortions in the mesh. Is there (by now) a way to accomplish this without a loss of detail?

[image: Mockup]
Mockup - the first three subdivisions have been applied

Comment: Try the data transfer modifier maybe?

Comment: This would be perfect, but i cant use it to transfer the positions of the individual vertices

Comment: Have you used *Wrap Method* = `Project` and ticked `[X] Negative` for direction for the *Shrinkwrap* modifier? This should prevent loss of details and distortion.

Comment: The shrinkwrap modifier itself isn't quite suited here as it has a problem capturing overhangs and keeping an even topology. Using project instead of nearest vertex gives worse results, especially for diagonal areas.